# Loading images to DataTable Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, datatable, devexpress

I want to display images in my XtraGrid (devexpress control). before I display the grid, I want to load the data into a datatable. unfortunately, I always get an "out of memory exception" during loading the images. I only use small images (300 kb). I figured out, that the exception only occurs, when I am in release mode.

here my code:

```
private void LoadData(List<string> categories)
    {
        SqlCeConnection cn;

        cn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);

        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cn.Open();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < categories.Count; j++)
        {
            string value = categories[j];

            // only if the connection string is not empty and a connection to the database was possible
            if (ConnectionString != string.Empty)
            {
                if (value == "Alle")
                {
                    DataTable dtAlle = new DataTable("Alle");

                    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dtAlle.Merge(data[i], false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
                    }

                    this.data.Add(dtAlle);
                }
                else
                {
                    string sql = "select * from " + value;

                    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, cn);
                    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable(value);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    List<string> imagePaths = new List<string>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        imagePaths.Add(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][0]));
                    }

                    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
                    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Vorschaubild", typeof(Image));
                    dt.Columns.Add(col);
                    dt.Columns["Vorschaubild"].SetOrdinal(0); // einfuegen an erster Stelle

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string imagePath = imagePaths[i];
                        if (imagePath != string.Empty)
                        {
                            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(imagePath);
                            string generatedPath = CheckIfPictureIsInClipboarPathAvailable(clipboardPath, info.Name);

                            if (generatedPath != string.Empty)
                            {
                                using (Image image = Image.FromFile(generatedPath))
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[i].SetField("Vorschaubild", image);
                                    image.Dispose();
                                }
                            }
                            else if (imagePath != string.Empty)
                            {
                                using (Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath))
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[i].SetField("Vorschaubild", image);
                                    image.Dispose();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    this.data.Add(dt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

any suggestions?
thanks,
tro

Comment: `300KB` is not small if you have `1000` rows or more :))

Comment: Which line the exception was thrown at?

Comment: here: using (Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath))

Comment: I tried now in debug mode and there is no exception?? now I am really confused.